# Libreoffice Calc run macro with HYPERLINK

Tags: macros, hyperlink, libreoffice, calc

I'm trying to use hyperlinks instead of buttons to run Basic macros. It seems to be more natural to me because hyperlinks are directly connected to a cell and buttons are not.
I'm using the following Formula:

`=HYPERLINK("vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module1.Test?language=Basic&location=document";"Check")`

It should call the Subroutine *Test* placed in the document's macros under *Standard.Module1* and display the Text 'Check' in the Cell it is written.

This works absolutely fine with libreoffice 3.6.1.2 but it doesn't work at all with version  4.1.4.2. I can't see any errors it just happens nothing at all. I tried to simply click the Hyperlink and also to hold CTRL and click it. Same result - nothing.

When I use a button the macro works as expected.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Calc. The protocol vnd.sun.star.script runs in hyperlink URLs in Writer still in version 4.2. But in Calc it runs not.

As a workaround you could have the following function attached to the sheet event "Double click". Then the macro runs if you double click the cell with the =HYPERLINK formula.

The last two versions are the results of my first ideas. I will let them in the answer because of comprehensibility reasons. But this last version is the best workaround in my opinion. It will closest work like the original vnd.sun.star.script: URL.

```
public function Doubelclicked(target) as Boolean

 if left(target.formula, 32) = "=HYPERLINK(""vnd.sun.star.script:" then
  sFormulaHyperlink = target.formula

  sMacroURLRaw = mid(sFormulaHyperlink, 13, instr(13, sFormulaHyperlink, ";") - 13)
  target.formula = "=""" & sMacroURLRaw 
  sMacroURL = target.string
  target.formula = sFormulaHyperlink

  oDisp = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

  dim args(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
  args(0).Name = "URL"
  args(0).Value = sMacroURL

  oFrame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
  oDisp.executeDispatch(oFrame, sMacroURL, "", 0, args)
 end if   

 Doubelclicked = false
end function
```

Here are the previous versions:

```
public function Doubelclicked(target) as Boolean
 if left(target.formula, 32) = "=HYPERLINK(""vnd.sun.star.script:" then
   sMacroURL = mid(target.formula, 13, instr(13, target.formula, chr(34))-13)
   oDisp = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
   oFrame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
   oDisp.executeDispatch(oFrame, sMacroURL, "", 0, Array())   
 end if
 Doubelclicked = false
end function
```

With this it is not possible to pass parameters in the macro URL. But if it only is the goal to get the address of the cell from which the macro was called, then this is possible because we have the target of the double click. So i have updated my workaround.

```
public function Doubelclicked(target) as Boolean
 if left(target.formula, 32) = "=HYPERLINK(""vnd.sun.star.script:" then

  lStartLocation = instr(13, target.formula,"&location=")
  if lStartLocation > 0 then
   lEndLocation = instr(lStartLocation + 1, target.formula,"&")
   if lEndLocation = 0 then lEndLocation = instr(lStartLocation + 1, target.formula,"""")

   sMacroURL = mid(target.formula, 13, lEndLocation - 13)
   'msgbox sMacroURL
   oDisp = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

   dim args(2) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
   args(0).Name = "TargetAddress"
   args(0).Value = target.AbsoluteName

   oFrame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
   oDisp.executeDispatch(oFrame, sMacroURL, "", 0, args)
  end if   
 end if
 Doubelclicked = false
end function
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you! That is almost what I was looking for. But this workaround doesn't function if I try to pass parameters with the URL like that: `=HYPERLINK("vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Module1.Test?language=Basic&location=document&R="&ROW()&"&C="&COLUMN()&"&S="&SHEET();"Check")`

Comment: With your suggested method the build-in functions are not evaluated and one just passes their names to the calling marco. Does there exist a simple trick for this extended problem?

Comment: Second problem: This solution (of course) changes the default behavior for a double click on a cell (jump into that cell to edit it) for any cell. Is there a way to use the else-case of the above to fall back to the default behavior for every cell that does not contain a hyperlink?

Comment: The second problem is easy to fix. The function has simply to return false. Then the doubleclick-event goes on and the default behavior for a double click will reappear.

But the first problem is not repairable for me. The main problem is, that I parse the formula, not the evaluated result of the formula. So the results of the ROW(), COLUMN() and SHEET() functions are not present while I parse the formula. I don't know a possibility to simply evaluate worksheet formulas with macro.

Comment: Well luckily I don't need other arguments at the moment. Your Solution works perfectly and fits my needs. I'm going to accept it. Although I hope that this bug will be fixed in the future...Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added a third version, which is the best in my opinion.